# how to track down why a node module is bundled

Tags: webpack

In a react/webpack project, I have a webpack config containing

```
{
    node: false 
}
```

Which to my understanding means "do not polyfill core node modules" that may get referenced in a browser context. So if there is a `require('crypto')` somewhere, I'd expect it to fail to build rather than polyfill with `node-libs-browser` for example.

I also analyzed `stats.json` via `webpack-visualizer-plugin` and found that a package `buffer` is getting bundled via `node-libs-browser`, e.g. running `npm ls buffer` I see

```
└─┬ webpack@4.41.2
  └─┬ node-libs-browser@2.2.1
    └── buffer@4.9.2
```

So aside from the fact that its my understanding that this shouldn't be possible, how do I go about tracking down which npm module caused this to be included by webpack? Am I reduced to grepping through all of node modules for `Buffer` references or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked to explicitly specify `node: {buffer: "empty"}`. Also please note it's `"empty"` - setting it to `false` failed to achieve the goal.